# how to slice a grouped Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, slice

I have a collection, which I have grouped by a particular key

```
$collection = Model::all()->groupBy('section_id');
```

This has left me with a collection containing several root nodes (sections) with each node containing a collection of multiple items.

```
print_r($collection->toArray());

Array
(
    [section_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [section_id] => section_1
                    ...
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [section_id] => section_1
                    ...
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [section_id] => section_1
                    ...
                )
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [section_id] => section_1
                    ...
                )
        )
    [section_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [section_id] => section_2
                    ...
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [section_id] => section_2
                    ...
                )
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [section_id] => section_2
                    ...
                )
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [section_id] => section_2
                    ...
                )
        )
)
```

This is great, but what I want to do now, is reduce the items in each section to just 2.

I have tried the following, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
$collection->map(function($section)
{
    $reduced_section = $section->slice(0,2);
    return $reduced_section;
});
```

Is this right, or is there a better (working) way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the result of the code you have tried?

Comment: It has no effect. Each section still contains all nested items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`take(2)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-take) instead and return the result directly. This function will pull the first two items of the collection.

Also, don't forget to assign the mapped collection back to the variable. [The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) states that the `map()` function will not modify the collection, but it will return a new modified collection.

```
$collection = $collection->map(function($section)
{
    return $section->take(2);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. It was the mapping of the collection back to another variable that I was missing. Thanks so much for your help.  I've been scratching my head for ages with that!!!